# Adding a class library to a Visual Web Part

Tags: web-part, visual-studio

I have created a SharePoint 2010 web part through Visual Studio 2010. All works nicely. However, I have several web parts to build in total and I have a class library that will contain standard methods I can reuse. When I add this class library to my web part solution I get an error when deploying to SharePoint:-

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'SPUtilities, Version=0.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2986f17b005315a6' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

What am I missing? I cannot seem to find any documentation on this on the internet - all examples show just the creation of a web part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK, so I figured out the problem was because my class library wasn't being registered with the GAC. I know when I built SP2007 projects with SPVisualDev it automatically registered dll's with the GAC. Is there a way to do this when creating web parts in VS2010, or will I need a custom script when deploying to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some messing around with the project I found the 'Advanced' tab on the Package.package design view that allows me to select extra project outputs to include in the build.